# Want to extract the table names and column names from SQL Statement

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am new to ANTLR, I got SQLite grammar from Github and I am able to generate the Lexer and Parser for that in Java.

I am trying to parse the SQL statement and trying to get Table names and Column names out, but I am getting the total Statement values when I am using the parser methods.

Can you help me out with the process I need to follow to get Table names and column names?

Comment: Could you provide a link to the grammar used and your source code?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't stick to **Antlr** you could use **JSqlParser**, which is based on **JavaCC**. Here is an example of how to achieve table and column names retrieval:

[Parsing table and column names from SQL/HQL Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40908062/parsing-table-and-column-names-from-sql-hql-java?rq=1)

It should be of no importance, which parser generator you are using, right?