# How to use JSQL Parser to retrieve table names from a query?

Tags: java, sql-parser, jsqlparser, general-sql-parser

I started to write code to parse a `SQL` query only to find out that there are `APIs` available for the same. When I saw JSQLParser [here](https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser), downloaded the `jar` using the given dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.jsqlparser</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsqlparser</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I found code to retrieve the column names from a `SQL` query as below:

**Main Class: Entry**

```
public class Entry {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Variables v = new Variables();
        try {
            v.getColumns("select 0 as c1,D1.c45 as c2,D1.c44 as c3,D1.c43 as c4,D1.c42 as c5,D1.c41 as c6,D1.c40 as c7,D1.c46 as c8,D1.c47 as c9,D1.c39 as c10,D1.c38 as c11,D1.c48 as c12,D1.c49 as c13,D1.c50 as c14,D1.c51 as c15,D1.c52 as c16,D1.c53 as c17,D1.c54 as c18,D1.c37 as c19,D1.c36 as c20,D1.c35 as c21,D1.c34 as c22,D1.c33 as c23,D1.c32 as c24,D1.c31 as c25,D1.c30 as c26,D1.c29 as c27,D1.c28 as c28,D1.c27 as c29,D1.c26 as c30,D1.c25 as c31,D1.c24 as c32,D1.c23 as c33,D1.c22 as c34,D1.c21 as c35,D1.c20 as c36,D1.c19 as c37,D1.c18 as c38,D1.c17 as c39,D1.c55 as c40,D1.c56 as c41,D1.c16 as c42,D1.c15 as c43,D1.c14 as c44,D1.c13 as c45,D1.c12 as c46,D1.c11 as c47,D1.c10 as c48,D1.c9 as c49,D1.c8 as c50,D1.c57 as c51,D1.c57 as c52,D1.c7 as c53,D1.c6 as c54,D1.c5 as c55,D1.c4 as c56,D1.c3 as c57,D1.c2 as c58,D1.c1 as c59 from (select sum(TABLE129.USD_ACTIVITY_AMOUNT) as c1, sum(ifnull(TABLE129.ENTERED_DEBIT , 0) - ifnull(TABLE129.ENTERED_CREDIT , 0)) as c2,sum(TABLE129.ENTERED_DEBIT) as c3,sum(TABLE129.ENTERED_CREDIT) as c4,sum(ifnull(TABLE129.ACCOUNTED_DEBIT , 0) - ifnull(TABLE129.ACCOUNTED_CREDIT , 0)) as c5,sum(TABLE129.ACCOUNTED_DEBIT) as c6,sum(TABLE129.ACCOUNTED_CREDIT) as c7,TABLE129.trading_partner_name_tp as c8,TABLE129.currency_code as c9,TABLE129.rt_LINE_NUM as c10,TABLE129.rt_LINE_DESCRIPTION as c11,TABLE129.concatenated_segments as c12,TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE9 as c13,TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE8 as c14,TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE7 as c15,TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE6 as c16,TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE5 as c17,TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE4 as c18,TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE3 as c19,TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE20 as c20,TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE2 as c21,TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE19 as c22,TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE18 as c23,TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE17 as c24,TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE16 as c25,TABLE129.rt_lines_attribute15 as c26,TABLE129.rt_lines_attribute14 as c27,TABLE129.rt_lines_attribute13 as c28,TABLE129.rt_lines_attribute12 as c29,TABLE129.rt_lines_attribute11 as c30,TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE10 as c31,TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE1 as c32,TABLE129.rt_SOURCE_NAME as c33,TABLE129.rt_CATEGORY_NAME as c34,TABLE129.rt_HEADER_ID as c35,TABLE129.rt_HEADER_NAME as c36,TABLE129.rt_CREATED_BY as c37,TABLE129.cost_center_name_cc as c38,TABLE129.company_code_name_lb as c39,TABLE129.batch_posted_date as c40,TABLE129.BATCH_NAME as c41,TABLE129.BATCH_ID as c42,TABLE129.batch_description as c43,TABLE129.account_name_acc as c44,T1334971.description as c45,T1330596.associated_bu as c46,T1330596.associated_le as c47,T9862411.cube_period as c48,T9862411.ledger_period_name as c49,T9862411.mk_period_num as c50,T9862411.qtr as c51,T9862411.mk_period_year as c52,T1338224.name as c53,T1354092.employee_name as c54,T1479416.attribute57 as c55,T1479416.attribute58 as c56,T9862411.gaap_month_num as c57 from ( au_mk_ledgers T1338224 /* DIM_mk_LEDGER */  inner join ( (au_drm_hier_company_code T1330596 /* DIM_COMPANY_CODE_HIER */  inner join (au_KETOL_period_dimension_v T9862411 /* DIM_KETOL_PERIOD */  inner join ( au_drm_hier_account T1334971 /* DIM_ACCOUNT_HIER */  inner join sld_mk_journals TABLE129 /* FACT_mk_DETAILS */  On T1334971.join_computed = TABLE129.join_account_computed) On T9862411.mk_period_year = TABLE129.period_year and T9862411.source_erp = TABLE129.source_system_name and T9862411.ledger_id = TABLE129.LEDGER_ID and T9862411.mk_period_name = TABLE129.period_name) On T1330596.join_fact_computed = TABLE129.join_company_code_computed) left outer join  au_fnd_user T1354092 /* DIM_HEADERS_CREATED_BY */  On TABLE129.rt_header_created_by = T1354092.user_id and TABLE129.source_system_name = T1354092.source_system_name) On T1338224.ledger_id = TABLE129.LEDGER_ID and T1338224.source_system_name = TABLE129.source_system_name) left outer join au_mk_rt_lines_addl_dffs T1479416 /* DIM_mk_rt_LINES_ADDL_DFFS */  On TABLE129.rt_HEADER_ID = T1479416.rt_header_id and TABLE129.rt_LINE_NUM = T1479416.rt_line_num and TABLE129.period_year = T1479416.period_year and TABLE129.source_system_name = T1479416.source_system_name  where  ( T1330596.drm_type = 'BASE' and T1334971.drm_type = 'E' and T1338224.name = 'USD Primary Ledger' and TABLE129.company_code_name_lb = 'LB_GIQ3' and TABLE129.account_name_acc = 'AC_1510301000' and (T9862411.ledger_period_name = 'OCT-19' or T9862411.ledger_period_name = 'SEP-19') )  group by T1330596.associated_le, T1330596.associated_bu, T1334971.description, T1338224.name, T9862411.mk_period_year, T9862411.mk_period_num, T9862411.cube_period, T9862411.qtr, T9862411.gaap_month_num, T9862411.ledger_period_name, TABLE129.rt_HEADER_ID, TABLE129.rt_LINE_NUM, TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE1, TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE2, TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE3, TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE4, TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE5, TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE6, TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE7, TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE8, TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE9, TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE10, TABLE129.rt_lines_attribute11, TABLE129.rt_lines_attribute12, TABLE129.rt_lines_attribute13, TABLE129.rt_lines_attribute14, TABLE129.rt_lines_attribute15, TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE16, TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE17, TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE18, TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE19, TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE20, TABLE129.currency_code, TABLE129.concatenated_segments, TABLE129.rt_CATEGORY_NAME, TABLE129.batch_posted_date, TABLE129.batch_description, TABLE129.BATCH_ID, TABLE129.rt_HEADER_NAME, TABLE129.BATCH_NAME, TABLE129.rt_CREATED_BY, TABLE129.rt_SOURCE_NAME, TABLE129.company_code_name_lb, TABLE129.account_name_acc, TABLE129.trading_partner_name_tp, TABLE129.cost_center_name_cc, TABLE129.rt_LINE_DESCRIPTION, T1354092.employee_name, T1479416.attribute57, T1479416.attribute58) D1 order by c17, c51, c10, c8, c9, c3, c2, c50, c11, c48, c47, c49, c23, c19, c18, c7, c6, c5, c24, c35, c37, c38, c39, c42, c43, c44, c45, c25, c26, c27, c28, c29, c30, c31, c32, c33, c34, c36, c40, c41, c46, c22, c4, c21, c20, c16, c15, c14 limit 10000001");
        } catch (JSQLParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Class using parser: Variables

```
public class Variables extends ExpressionDeParser {
    public List<String> getColumns(String query) throws JSQLParserException {
        CCJSqlParserManager parseSql = new CCJSqlParserManager();
        Statement stmnt = parseSql.parse(new StringReader(query));
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        if(stmnt instanceof Select) {
            Select selectStatement = (Select) stmnt; //convert to Select Statement
            PlainSelect ps = (PlainSelect)selectStatement.getSelectBody();
            List<SelectItem> selectitems = ps.getSelectItems();
            for(SelectItem i: selectitems) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
        return list;
     }
}
```

I tried to retrieve the tables using below method:
I tried this

```
public  List<String> getTables(String query) throws JSQLParserException {
    CCJSqlParserManager parseSql = new CCJSqlParserManager();
    Statement stmnt = parseSql.parse(new StringReader(query));

    List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
    if(stmnt instanceof  Select) {
        Select select = (Select) stmnt;
        PlainSelect ps = (PlainSelect) select.getSelectBody();
        List<Table> tables = ps.getIntoTables();
        for(Table t: tables) {
            System.out.println(t);
        }
    }
    return lst;
}
```

But it is printing NULL.

The queries I am using are of `Postgresql`.
The method: getColumns is printing the columns correctly. I dont know how can I print table names from the query passed. Is there a specific method to get table names from the query ? 
Could anyone let me know how can extract table names from a given query using `JSQL` Parser ?

Comment: JSqlParser uses the visitor pattern to dive into a parsed SQL statement. First you should answer the question, if you want to extract also tables and columns from used subqueries. That would determine, where to stop your search. Here are two variants described extracting those values: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40908062/parsing-table-and-column-names-from-sql-hql-java.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.List;

import net.sf.jsqlparser.JSQLParserException;
import net.sf.jsqlparser.expression.Expression;
import net.sf.jsqlparser.expression.Function;
import net.sf.jsqlparser.parser.CCJSqlParserManager;
import net.sf.jsqlparser.schema.Column;
import net.sf.jsqlparser.statement.select.PlainSelect;
import net.sf.jsqlparser.statement.select.Select;
import net.sf.jsqlparser.statement.select.SelectExpressionItem;
import net.sf.jsqlparser.statement.select.SelectItem;

public class TableDetailsParser {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String statement;
        try {
            CCJSqlParserManager parseSql = new CCJSqlParserManager();
            statement = "select 0 as c1,D1.c45 as c2,D1.c44 as c3,D1.c43 as c4,D1.c42 as c5,D1.c41 as c6,D1.c40 as c7,D1.c46 as c8,D1.c47 as c9,D1.c39 as c10,D1.c38 as c11,D1.c48 as c12,D1.c49 as c13,D1.c50 as c14,D1.c51 as c15,D1.c52 as c16,D1.c53 as c17,D1.c54 as c18,D1.c37 as c19,D1.c36 as c20,D1.c35 as c21,D1.c34 as c22,D1.c33 as c23,D1.c32 as c24,D1.c31 as c25,D1.c30 as c26,D1.c29 as c27,D1.c28 as c28,D1.c27 as c29,D1.c26 as c30,D1.c25 as c31,D1.c24 as c32,D1.c23 as c33,D1.c22 as c34,D1.c21 as c35,D1.c20 as c36,D1.c19 as c37,D1.c18 as c38,D1.c17 as c39,D1.c55 as c40,D1.c56 as c41,D1.c16 as c42,D1.c15 as c43,D1.c14 as c44,D1.c13 as c45,D1.c12 as c46,D1.c11 as c47,D1.c10 as c48,D1.c9 as c49,D1.c8 as c50,D1.c57 as c51,D1.c57 as c52,D1.c7 as c53,D1.c6 as c54,D1.c5 as c55,D1.c4 as c56,D1.c3 as c57,D1.c2 as c58,D1.c1 as c59 from (select sum(TABLE129.USD_ACTIVITY_AMOUNT) as c1, sum(ifnull(TABLE129.ENTERED_DEBIT , 0) - ifnull(TABLE129.ENTERED_CREDIT , 0)) as c2,sum(TABLE129.ENTERED_DEBIT) as c3,sum(TABLE129.ENTERED_CREDIT) as c4,sum(ifnull(TABLE129.ACCOUNTED_DEBIT , 0) - ifnull(TABLE129.ACCOUNTED_CREDIT , 0)) as c5,sum(TABLE129.ACCOUNTED_DEBIT) as c6,sum(TABLE129.ACCOUNTED_CREDIT) as c7,TABLE129.trading_partner_name_tp as c8,TABLE129.currency_code as c9,TABLE129.rt_LINE_NUM as c10,TABLE129.rt_LINE_DESCRIPTION as c11,TABLE129.concatenated_segments as c12,TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE9 as c13,TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE8 as c14,TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE7 as c15,TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE6 as c16,TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE5 as c17,TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE4 as c18,TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE3 as c19,TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE20 as c20,TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE2 as c21,TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE19 as c22,TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE18 as c23,TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE17 as c24,TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE16 as c25,TABLE129.rt_lines_attribute15 as c26,TABLE129.rt_lines_attribute14 as c27,TABLE129.rt_lines_attribute13 as c28,TABLE129.rt_lines_attribute12 as c29,TABLE129.rt_lines_attribute11 as c30,TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE10 as c31,TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE1 as c32,TABLE129.rt_SOURCE_NAME as c33,TABLE129.rt_CATEGORY_NAME as c34,TABLE129.rt_HEADER_ID as c35,TABLE129.rt_HEADER_NAME as c36,TABLE129.rt_CREATED_BY as c37,TABLE129.cost_center_name_cc as c38,TABLE129.company_code_name_lb as c39,TABLE129.batch_posted_date as c40,TABLE129.BATCH_NAME as c41,TABLE129.BATCH_ID as c42,TABLE129.batch_description as c43,TABLE129.account_name_acc as c44,T1334971.description as c45,T1330596.associated_bu as c46,T1330596.associated_le as c47,T9862411.cube_period as c48,T9862411.ledger_period_name as c49,T9862411.mk_period_num as c50,T9862411.qtr as c51,T9862411.mk_period_year as c52,T1338224.name as c53,T1354092.employee_name as c54,T1479416.attribute57 as c55,T1479416.attribute58 as c56,T9862411.gaap_month_num as c57 from ( au_mk_ledgers T1338224 /* DIM_mk_LEDGER */  inner join ( (au_drm_hier_company_code T1330596 /* DIM_COMPANY_CODE_HIER */  inner join (au_KETOL_period_dimension_v T9862411 /* DIM_KETOL_PERIOD */  inner join ( au_drm_hier_account T1334971 /* DIM_ACCOUNT_HIER */  inner join sld_mk_journals TABLE129 /* FACT_mk_DETAILS */  On T1334971.join_computed = TABLE129.join_account_computed) On T9862411.mk_period_year = TABLE129.period_year and T9862411.source_erp = TABLE129.source_system_name and T9862411.ledger_id = TABLE129.LEDGER_ID and T9862411.mk_period_name = TABLE129.period_name) On T1330596.join_fact_computed = TABLE129.join_company_code_computed) left outer join  au_fnd_user T1354092 /* DIM_HEADERS_CREATED_BY */  On TABLE129.rt_header_created_by = T1354092.user_id and TABLE129.source_system_name = T1354092.source_system_name) On T1338224.ledger_id = TABLE129.LEDGER_ID and T1338224.source_system_name = TABLE129.source_system_name) left outer join au_mk_rt_lines_addl_dffs T1479416 /* DIM_mk_rt_LINES_ADDL_DFFS */  On TABLE129.rt_HEADER_ID = T1479416.rt_header_id and TABLE129.rt_LINE_NUM = T1479416.rt_line_num and TABLE129.period_year = T1479416.period_year and TABLE129.source_system_name = T1479416.source_system_name  where  ( T1330596.drm_type = 'BASE' and T1334971.drm_type = 'E' and T1338224.name = 'USD Primary Ledger' and TABLE129.company_code_name_lb = 'LB_GIQ3' and TABLE129.account_name_acc = 'AC_1510301000' and (T9862411.ledger_period_name = 'OCT-19' or T9862411.ledger_period_name = 'SEP-19') )  group by T1330596.associated_le, T1330596.associated_bu, T1334971.description, T1338224.name, T9862411.mk_period_year, T9862411.mk_period_num, T9862411.cube_period, T9862411.qtr, T9862411.gaap_month_num, T9862411.ledger_period_name, TABLE129.rt_HEADER_ID, TABLE129.rt_LINE_NUM, TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE1, TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE2, TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE3, TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE4, TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE5, TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE6, TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE7, TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE8, TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE9, TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE10, TABLE129.rt_lines_attribute11, TABLE129.rt_lines_attribute12, TABLE129.rt_lines_attribute13, TABLE129.rt_lines_attribute14, TABLE129.rt_lines_attribute15, TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE16, TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE17, TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE18, TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE19, TABLE129.rt_LINES_ATTRIBUTE20, TABLE129.currency_code, TABLE129.concatenated_segments, TABLE129.rt_CATEGORY_NAME, TABLE129.batch_posted_date, TABLE129.batch_description, TABLE129.BATCH_ID, TABLE129.rt_HEADER_NAME, TABLE129.BATCH_NAME, TABLE129.rt_CREATED_BY, TABLE129.rt_SOURCE_NAME, TABLE129.company_code_name_lb, TABLE129.account_name_acc, TABLE129.trading_partner_name_tp, TABLE129.cost_center_name_cc, TABLE129.rt_LINE_DESCRIPTION, T1354092.employee_name, T1479416.attribute57, T1479416.attribute58) D1 order by c17, c51, c10, c8, c9, c3, c2, c50, c11, c48, c47, c49, c23, c19, c18, c7, c6, c5, c24, c35, c37, c38, c39, c42, c43, c44, c45, c25, c26, c27, c28, c29, c30, c31, c32, c33, c34, c36, c40, c41, c46, c22, c4, c21, c20, c16, c15, c14 limit 10000001";
            Select select = (Select) parseSql.parse(new StringReader(statement));
            PlainSelect plain = (PlainSelect) select.getSelectBody();
            List<SelectItem> selectitems = plain.getSelectItems();
            for (int index = 0; index < selectitems.size(); index++) {
                Expression expressionIns = ((SelectExpressionItem) selectitems.get(index)).getExpression();
                if (expressionIns instanceof Column) {
                    Column columnInstance = (Column) expressionIns;
                    System.out.println("Table Name :: "+columnInstance.getTable());
                    System.out.println("Column  Name :: "+columnInstance.getColumnName());
                } else if (expressionIns instanceof Function) {
                    Function functionIns = (Function) expressionIns;
                    System.out.println("Function Name :: "+functionIns.getName());
                }
            }

        } catch (JSQLParserException exceptionInstance) {
            exceptionInstance.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Output :

```
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c45
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c44
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c43
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c42
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c41
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c40
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c46
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c47
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c39
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c38
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c48
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c49
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c50
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c51
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c52
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c53
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c54
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c37
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c36
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c35
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c34
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c33
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c32
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c31
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c30
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c29
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c28
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c27
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c26
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c25
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c24
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c23
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c22
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c21
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c20
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c19
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c18
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c17
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c55
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c56
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c16
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c15
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c14
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c13
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c12
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c11
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c10
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c9
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c8
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c57
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c57
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c7
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c6
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c5
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c4
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c3
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c2
Table Name :: D1
Column  Name :: c1
```

Here below is the code which can extract the table name and column names with alais and i am trying to tune this to include the select with functions as well

Comment: I added the method: getTables I tried to get table names. Please check it in the question.

Comment: Ok. I am going to try your code in the meanwhile. Will post the outcome very soon.

Answer (score 0):

```
private List<String> getTables(String query) throws JSQLParserException {
    CCJSqlParserManager parseSql = new CCJSqlParserManager();
    Statement stmnt = parseSql.parse(new StringReader(query));
    TablesNamesFinder tablesNamesFinder = new TablesNamesFinder();
    return tablesNamesFinder.getTableList(stmnt);
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

With `jsqlparser` version 4.5,  code like this:

```
Statement statement = CCJSqlParserUtil.parse(sql);
TablesNamesFinder tablesNamesFinder = new TablesNamesFinder();
Set<String> tableNames = new HashSet<>(tablesNamesFinder.getTableList(statement));
```